# Merge [filenotfound] and [filenotfoundexception] into [file-not-found]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

These three tags all refer to the same concept, with the slight exception of [filenotfoundexception](/questions/tagged/filenotfoundexception).

While we would usually merge the two smaller tags into the bigger tag, I feel that [filenotfound](/questions/tagged/filenotfound) and [filenotfoundexception](/questions/tagged/filenotfoundexception) should be merged into [file-not-found](/questions/tagged/file-not-found) in order to relieve any confusion for new users.

The [filenotfoundexception](/questions/tagged/filenotfoundexception) tag gives off the impression that it is for languages that actually have a `FileNotFoundException`. This may confuse users and may have been the reason for the creation of the [filenotfound](/questions/tagged/filenotfound) and [file-not-found](/questions/tagged/file-not-found) tags.

Ergo, we should merge [filenotfound](/questions/tagged/filenotfound) and [filenotfoundexception](/questions/tagged/filenotfoundexception) into [file-not-found](/questions/tagged/file-not-found) and also transfer the wiki from [filenotfoundexception](/questions/tagged/filenotfoundexception) to [file-not-found](/questions/tagged/file-not-found). Make sure that if the wiki is transferred that we remove all references to exceptions.

Comment: Ok, questions like this show up far too often around here...there *must* a way to make it easier for the community to handle this on their own.

Comment: Ahhhh, so many boxes! O.O

Comment: @animuson I know right?

Comment: [tag:file-not-found]? Come on, it needs to be [FILE_NOT_FOUND] ;)

Comment: PS, I've killed off [tag:filenotfound].

Comment: Cool. Now if we can only merge [tag:filenotfoundexception] into [tag:file-not-found] and migrate the wiki.

Comment: I suggested an edit for file-not-found, based on (very) lightly modified content from filenotfoundexception. It has been approved. So, we're done here; on to the retagging!

Answer (score 2):

I think they could all be merged with some light tag wiki editing. I'd suggest:

> An error, exit status, or exception that indicates that the file denoted by a specified
>   pathname could not be found.

which would make it clear that "file-not-found" applies to the general case, and not just languages with exception handling.